# What is the .net framework Reference Assemblies Facades folder used for?

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

I noticed there is a Facades folder within each of the .NETFramework Reference Assemblies folder. Starting from v4.5. All the assemblies in these folders are very small, and only contain metadata.
Examples:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7\Facades
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.1\Facades
```

I am curious and want to know what are these used for? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/history/evolution-of-design-time-assemblies.md

Comment: @HansPassant This is the best article about dot Net assemblies I have every read! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

**Type Forwarding** is a concept in which you can move a type declaration from one assembly (say A) to another assembly (say B), without the need to recompile the applications that use the first assembly (A).

Facade Assemblies contain only the Type Forwards

Facade assemblies match the identity of contract assemblies (these are similar to reference assemblies) and type forwards all the types (declared in contract assemblies) to their respective implementation assemblies.

Thus, at design times, you compile your application against a set of contract assemblies, on the other hand, at runtime, the applications lookup for types in Facade assemblies (since they match the identity of the contract assembly) and type forwards in the assembly, the type declarations are fetched from the implementation assemblies.

Since Facade Assemblies only contain the type forwards, they are very small in size.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer for .NET Framework, but for .NET Core / .NET (5+), reference assemblies are contained in a 'Pack'. There are packs for:

- Targeting packs
- Runtime packs
- App host packs

Reference assemblies are in the targeting packs (at `C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs`)

The reference assmemblies are referenced only at build time. At run time, the 'app host' decides which *real* assemblies to use based on architecture and platform.

More information can be found [in this blog post](https://dunnhq.com/posts/2021/anatomy-of-a-dotnet-app/).